# Can investigators easily avoid being stuck in the Bent Pyramid and avoid the Sanity loss from Nephre-Ka's reckoning?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids

This is a multi-faceted question and revolves around Nephren-Ka's reckoning which says

> Each investigator may move 1 space toward the Bent Pyramid. Then each investigator that did not move loses 1 Sanity.

If I end up moved to the Bent Pyramid, I can spend 0 actions moving away from it as far as Tel El-Amarna, Cairo, or Alexandria as a function of the rule enabling me to

> ...move along any number of interconnected Local paths without performing an action.

If the reckoning hits when I am in Cairo, I end up moving one space toward the Bent Pyramid and end up in The Pyramids, correct?

It seems trivially easy to avoid being caught there. Am I misunderstanding any part of this?  Part of my confusion may be not understanding why being drawn toward the Bent Pyramid is such a big deal apart from some of the time working against the movement objectives of my investigators.

Answer (score 4):

1. You're being drawn there from anywhere on the board, not just from locations that have convenient local paths.
2. If you're already on the Bent Pyramid, then you'll lose 1 Sanity as you did not move.
3. It's not necessary a big deal. Some Ancient Ones have effects that are more thematic than hindering. I think this is the case here. Pretty often this effect helps investigators as it can move you into desired position, and you may take it into account while planning your travels.

Comment: Thanks, I understood points 1 and 2 already, but the reminder that it could be simply for flavor or theme does make it set a lot better and not make me feel like I'm misinterpreting something.  Of course, the fact that it isn't a particularly deadly effect isn't doing anything to stop us from losing horribly in our first playthrough against Nephren-Ka! :P